# How to convert a regular multivariat dataframe to a 3D shape for LSTM fit in Keras?

Tags: r, machine-learning, keras, lstm, reshape

I‘m trying to fit a LSTM model on some data using keras in Rstudio. Main goal is to predict the stock price using several features such as historic stock information, Covid information etc. Please see an excerpt of the training data. (testing data looks the same). Data will be normalized and scaled as well.

```
> head(X_train)
       date  BNTX.Open  BNTX.High   BNTX.Low BNTX.Volume  VIX.Kurs
1 -1.726310 -0.9389774 -0.9147491 -0.9406800  -1.0391883 -1.044287
2 -1.718655 -0.9171379 -0.8772236 -0.9010828  -0.9745892 -1.060324
3 -1.710999 -0.8416828 -0.8386974 -0.8894619  -0.8806268 -1.065984
4 -1.703344 -0.8737693 -0.8639145 -0.8571816  -1.0318373 -1.098059
5 -1.695688 -0.8504807 -0.8601119 -0.8729989  -1.0149996 -1.183905
6 -1.688033 -0.8666275 -0.8773236 -0.9214194  -0.9598871 -1.182018
  New_deaths New_cases
1  -1.900206 -1.529246
2  -1.900206 -1.529233
3  -1.900206 -1.529246
4  -1.900206 -1.529246
5  -1.900206 -1.529246
6  -1.900206 -1.529246
> head(y_train)
  BNTX.Adjusted
1    -0.9144203
2    -0.8675775
3    -0.8803998
4    -0.8622004
5    -0.8811237
6    -0.9182463
```

Please see below current code of my base LSTM model.

```
dim(X_train)#[1] 452   8

modelLSTM <- keras_model_sequential() %>% 
  layer_lstm(input_shape =  c(8, 1), units = 8, activation = "relu", return_sequences = FALSE) %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 8, activation = "relu") %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 1)
summary(modelLSTM)

modelLSTM %>% compile(loss = "mse", optimizer ="rmsprop", metrics = "mae")
modelLSTM <- modelLSTM %>% fit(X_train,y_train, epochs = 100, batch_size = 32, callback =list(callback_early_stopping(monitor = "val_loss", patience = 10, restore_best_weights = TRUE)) , validation_split = 0.2)

modelLSTM %>% evaluate(X_test, y_test)
pred_testy <- modelLSTM %>% predict(X_test)
mean((y_test-pred_testy)^2)
plot(y_test,pred_testy )
```

For that matter i tried several approaches. For me the most easiest way would be to insert the data directly to the „input_shape“ argument in the first LSTM layer.
I fear that the model is not working as it should be, even though there is no technical error.

As a second attemp I tried to follow this tutorials and code here: [brandonyph RNN tutorial](https://github.com/brandonyph/Introduction-to-RNN-in-R). These lines seem to work with some type of generator functions.
I was expecting it to work similar to previous code.
However, I can‘t understand where to differantiate between my features (X_train or X_test) and y-target (y_train and y_test) in order to perfom a predcition (on target) on my testing data. This brings me back to the title question.